# Combining two tables and defining a third field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

1st table:

```
NAMES
-----------------------------
CD_SPECIES        SPECIES
1                 Sp1  
2                 Sp2
3                 Sp3
```

Created with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
CD_SPECIES serial PRIMARY KEY,
SPECIES varchar(64));
```

and the 2nd one:

```
COEFFICIENTS
-------------------------------
CD_COEFFICIENT      COEFFICIENT
1                   Coeff1 
2                   Coeff2
```

created with

```
CREATE TABLE COEFFICIENTS (
CD_COEFFICIENT serial PRIMARY KEY,
COEFFICIENT varchar(64) --HOLDS A COEFFICIENT NAME
);
```

I want to create a third table with the following

```
COMBINED TABLE
----------------------------------------
SPECIES        COEFFICIENT       CVALUE
Sp1            Coeff1            
Sp1            Coeff2
Sp2            Coeff1            
Sp2            Coeff2
Sp3            Coeff1            
Sp3            Coeff2
```

where `CVALUE` is the column that will hold `float` type data defined by me.

How should I create the 3rd table?

NOTE: If there is another way of combining these tables feel free to share it (e.g. combining the keys etc.). I am very new to databases!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this with `create table as` and a `cross join`:

```
create table thirdtable as 
    select s.species, c.coefficient, cast(12345 as real) as cvalue
    from species cross join
         coefficients;
```

Comment: Then how can I change the values of cvalue?

Comment: @MaR1oC . . . You would use `update` to change it.  Perhaps you want to ask another question on how you put in the values that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create the 3rd table, like you have done for other two.

And then insert the records in this 3rd table taking the data from a join of table 1 and 2.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (col1, col2) values (select tab1.SPECIES.tab2.COEFFICIENT from tab1,tab2
where tab1.CD_SPECIES  = tab2.CD_COEFFICIENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS 
 SELECT SPECIES ,COEFFICIENT, NULL::float 
   FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ffdc/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can create table as a result of a select like

```
create table newtable as
select table1.column1, table2.tolumn2 from table1, table2 
where table1.id=table2.id
```